# epplus range merge AutoFilter

Tags: filter, merge, range, epplus

I'm trying to add the property

var range = sheet.Cells ["A6: R6"];
range.AutoFilter = true;

It does not work, apply the filter to all columns of the merge. How to solve? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space in your cell range string.  In other words:

```
var range = sheet.Cells ["A6: R6"];
```

Should be:

```
var range = sheet.Cells ["A6:R6"];
```

That will definitely trip it up.  If that doesnt fix it post more of your code.